# How to send a named function to a boost::phoenix expression

Tags: c++, boost, boost-phoenix

I can't figure out how to send a named function as an argument to another function, and include the argument in a phoenix lambda expression.

Here's the minimal example that I could think of.

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/phoenix.hpp>

using namespace std;
namespace ph = boost::phoenix;
using ph::arg_names::arg1;

template <typename Predicate>
void foo(vector<int> &v, Predicate p) {
  for_each(v.begin(), v.end(),
      if_(p(arg1))
      [
        cout << "found " << arg1 << ", "
      ]);
  cout << endl;
}

bool is_odd(int i) {
  return (i % 2 == 1);
}

main() {
  vector<int> v(10);
  int i = 1;
  generate(v.begin(), v.end(), ph::ref(i)++);
  cout << "looking for odd ones ";
  foo(v, arg1 % 2 == 1);

  cout << "using named function ";
  //foo(v, is_odd);
  //foo(v, &is_odd);
  //foo(v, ph::bind(&is_odd, arg1));
  //foo(v, boost::bind(&is_odd, _1));
}
```

I can't figure out how to send the `is_odd()` function to `foo()` as a predicate.

**Note:**
In my actual code the predicate is actually a member function of `arg1` (`arg1` is of `class Bar`, and I need `Bar::is_odd` as predicate). I've tried the `(arg1->*&Bar::is_odd)()` style but it didn't work. I'm not including this in this example for simplicity.

**Update:**
Here's the C++11 version of the same code. This one works well, however, I'd like to make it work with phoenix, as I can't use C++11

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

template <typename Predicate>
void foo(vector<int> &v, Predicate p) {
  for_each(begin(v), end(v),
      [&] (int i) {
        if (p(i))
          cout << "found " << i << ", ";
      });
  cout << endl;
}

bool is_odd(int i) {
  return (i % 2 == 1);
}

main() {
  vector<int> v={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
  cout << "looking for odd ones ";
  foo(v, [] (int i) {return (i%2 == 1);});

  cout << "using named function ";
  foo(v, &is_odd);
}
```

Comment: Your first code snippet also drips of the use of c++11 features...

Comment: right, sorry about that. Fixed.

Comment: heh. nice job - bit phoenix happy (or `std::iota` not in TR1?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be another, simpler, way to do this, but one alternative is using a phoenix function(tested on g++ 4.8.1 without -std=c++11):

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/phoenix.hpp>

using namespace std;
namespace ph = boost::phoenix;
using ph::arg_names::arg1;

bool is_odd(int i) {
  return (i % 2 == 1);
}

struct is_odd_impl
{
  template <typename Sig>
  struct result;

  template <typename This, typename Arg>
  struct result<This(Arg)>
  {
    typedef bool type;
  };

  template <typename Arg>
  bool operator()(const Arg& arg) const
  {
    return is_odd(arg);
    //return arg.is_odd();
  }
};

ph::function<is_odd_impl> lazy_is_odd = is_odd_impl();

template <typename Predicate>
void foo(vector<int> &v, Predicate p) {
  for_each(v.begin(), v.end(),
      if_(p(arg1))
      [
        cout << "found " << arg1 << ", "
      ]);
  cout << endl;
}



int main() {
  vector<int> v(10);
  int cont = 1;
  std::generate(v.begin(),v.end(),ph::ref(cont)++);

  cout << "looking for odd ones ";
  foo(v, arg1 % 2 == 1);

  cout << "using named function ";
  foo(v, lazy_is_odd);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I could not make this work with the BOOST_PHOENIX_ADAPT macros, but your code works.